# Read and print string, C

Tags: c

I have a function that reads data from from array, but, when I'd like to print data instead of the name I get some trash: `4273 �нз знзнз`. Where I made mistake?

A function, where `student_list[i] = "4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333 знзнз"`:

```
int debt() {
  char name[100];
  char test[5];
  int group;
  int exam;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d %s", &group, name, &exam, test);

    printf("%d %s %s\n", group, name, test);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use unicode in C like this.

Comment: It could be the encoding , you can try using wchar

Comment: `"знзнз"` `char test[5];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because size of char type in memory isn't enough for save unicode characters you should depend on your compiler use other types of data type like wchar or I can offer to you ,It's better use cuchar.h  header file and solve your problem